# django + nginx + uwsgi + ssl giving post 403 forbidden error from react?

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx, uwsgi

I run django + nginx + uwsgi with https in production, and the front end uses react.

The react code requests the production site for the apis during development. When js code uses POST it causes a 403 forbidden. I think this occurs because the host and referer headers are different when posting from localhost to the production site with ssl. It was working fine when I was using gunicorn. I would like to find a workaround so that I can POST from the js code while developing the react app.

This is my nignx conf.

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.tratoli.com,tratoli.com;
        #return 301 https://$host$1;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.tratoli.com$1 permanent;
    }
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-available/tratoli_ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sites-available/tratoli_ssl.key;
        server_name www.tratoli.com;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                alias /home/ubuntu/django/new_backend/favicon.ico;
         }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/django/new_backend/static/;
    }
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///home/ubuntu/django/new_backend/tratoli/tratoli.sock;
    }

    location /chat/ {
        proxy_pass http://52.66.167.160:8000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_set_header Origin '';
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|ttf|woff|otf)$ {
        root /home/ubuntu/django/new_backend/;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location =/sw.js {
        root /home/ubuntu/django/new_backend/static/react_mobile/js/;
    }

  }
```

And this is my uwsgi ini file

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /home/ubuntu/django/new_backend/tratoli/tratoli.sock
uid = 1000
gid = 33
chdir = /home/ubuntu/django/new_backend/tratoli/
wsgi-file = tratoli/wsgi.py
processes = 4
threads = 30
chmod-socket = 777
env = DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT="production"
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

Also I have tried setting CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in django settings and even that is not helping.
Any Ideas?

Comment: If it works with gunicorn, why did you switch?

Comment: uwsgi is much better. There is a lot more configurability and seems to be much better at load balancing...

Comment: So if you check logs of all these component where do you see the error initiated?

Comment: I think the error is initiated by django in its csrfmiddleware... Even if you put localhost inside CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS becuase a POST request from localhost is not secure, it rejects it...